# Saving a .properties file in Eclipse causes it to change the entire file

Tags: java, eclipse

My messageResource.properties contains Japanese characters such as the following:

Please take note of the "all caps" characters.

```
label1=\u5185\u5BB9
label2=\u60C5\u5831\u63D0\u4F9B\u5143
label3=\u60C5\u5831\u63D0\u4F9B\u65E5
label4=\u8A73\u7D30\u8AAC\u660E
```

After changing and saving it, the entire file became like this, from all caps, everything is now small caps:

```
label1=\u5185\u5bb9
label2=\u60c5\u5831\u63d0\u4f9b\u5143
label3=\u60c5\u5831\u63d0\u4f9b\u65e5
label4=\u8a73\u7d30\u8aac\u660e
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What problem do you have with lowercase?

Comment: It's just that the SVN log will show that each line in the file was changed, which I find a bit cumbersome when I have to investigate.

Comment: So convert it once to lowercase and leave it like that.

Comment: Other team members have it the other way around. We agree to define a single rule, but the problem is that we don't know how.

Comment: I'd do that, but that will just switch the problem to them. Whenever they save the lower case properties file, it will be automatically converted to uppercase.

Comment: How do you edit properties files? Are you using any plugin for that?

Comment: Yes. I'm using this one http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/properties-editor#.U6Ful1foEZw

Comment: What the rest of your team is using?

Comment: I wanted to make sure so I checked with them, and they're using the same thing as mine.